# Unable to create bean while loading class at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two projects which works differently. First one is used for class loading and second one has its class which is used for doing some processing work.

In first project I am loading the class and instead of creating new instance for invoking the method I am only using application context.

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

ClassLoader loader = null;

try {
    loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{new   

File(plugins + "/" + pluginName + "/" + pluginName +   

".jar").toURI().toURL()}, getClass().getClassLoader());

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Class<?> clazz = null;

try {

    clazz = Class.forName("com.sample.Specific", true, loader);

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}

Method method = null;
try {
    method = clazz.getMethod("run",new Class[]{});
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    method.invoke(context.getBean(clazz),new Object[]{});
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In Second Project I have this example :

```
package com.sample

@Service
public class Specific {

@Autowired
private FD fd;


public void run(){

    fd.init();

}

}
```

As I have mentioned these are two different projects. So when I run the first project with Main class , then it says that --

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sample.Specific' in your
>   configuration.

How can I create the bean?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not able to find this class, into your component scan configuration you need to declare the package where your beans live.

Comment: Actually the thing is i am loading this class at runtime and i declare the package at once there only. Can you let me know some point or code to declare the package where my beans live please. As such i dont know how to create beans at runtime

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation lvan . Here the actual question is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115102/how-to-create-a-bean-at-runtime-at-the-time-while-using-class-loading-java-refl

Comment: Can you tell me what is declared into your web.xml between context-param tags?

Comment: If you don't have those tags then check into your appname-servlet.xml if you have <context:component-scan base-package = "com.sample" /> if the answer is no i think you have any class like appConfig annotated with @Configuration @ComponentScan("here.you.package"), if the answer i no please post your application structure folders with configuration and classes to help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i have a spring boot project. I dont maintain these files.

Comment: I have only the appConfig Class. But i can not annotate with @ComponetScan as i dont know the package name at runtime . I load the class at runtime

Comment: add the annotation @Component to your Service class this should be work

Comment: I had done this. But i am not able to get the result. Same problem still persist

Comment: The thing basically i am doing is that i have a class annotated with @ Service and @ Component and i load this class at runtime in different project which has no link with this project . So, when i load it then i get the instance using @ Autowired ApplicationContext. then it falis because it requires bean of that particular class which you are loading.

Comment: You are using the project as a dependency declared in your pom.xml?

Comment: No. I am not using dependency in pom.xml. I want only to add the class at runtime and get that class instance and work with it. If i add dependency that it works smoothly, Can you help me out in this as i am having very much problem in this from so many days

Comment: The thing is when i get the instance using newInstance method then i am not able to do autowiring and other things in that class which i am loading at runtime